# close previous Activity and open new activity on Item click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Hi everyone,
             I have created  a listview which is available on left side. On each item click opens new activity opens but when I traverse among listitems the new activity does not open after first attempt. I have closed the present activity in each case with  finish() method. but it does not seems to work. here is code snippet ..let me know if anybody could help..appreciated

```
    if (listname.equalsIgnoreCase("Time Table")) {
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimeTable.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Attendance.this.finish();
    } else if (listname.equalsIgnoreCase("Announcements")) {
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Announcement.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Attendance.this.finish();
    }
```

Comment: add `FLAG_CLEAR_TOP` to your intent , and use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` or use `noHistory` in your manifest file for your `<activity>` tag

Comment: Thnaks, but it does not seems to work I have made the changes and also tried bring to front flag...intent=new Intent(TimeTable.this,Announcement.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: try other options ( noHistory )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my own problem, the issue was that I was not forwarding the some needed values to next activity such as userid, password etc. So I used SharedPreferences to pass the needed values on other activities. Here is example ..I hope it can be useful for others.
This is now created and committed shared preference

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("ABCPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("UserId", login);  
                        editor.putString("password", password);
                        editor.putString("IsInside", Inside);
                        editor.putString("UserType", "S");
                        editor.commit();
```

To access values through shared preference, It is simple

```
String listname = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                    String userid = getSharedPreferences("UMSPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE).getString("UserId", login);
                    String paswrd = getSharedPreferences("UMSPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE).getString("password", password);
```

Comment: It's not really clear how this solved your problem or what exactly the issue turned out being. Also, if you're just forwarding values from one activity to the next, why not pass them as [intent extras](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent)?

Comment: I used Intent extras but it did not work out, may be because when you traverse among list items, the initial values you need from first activity will not be available to third or fourth activity call on item click. That is the reason I used SharedPreferences. I hope you understand. Correct me if I am wrong...